# how to suggest name inside bundle in chisel3.2?

Tags: chisel

I'm using the suggestName API for IO(), for example

```scala
class TestModule extends MultiIOModule{
  val AXI = IO(new AXIWriteIO(32,32,4)).suggestName("axi")
  val S_AXI = IO(Flipped(new AXIWriteIO(32,32,4)))

  AXI.AW.suggestName("aw")
  AXI <> S_AXI
}
```

It works with the "axi" part, but not the "aw" part.

The suggestName also does not work inside the bundle definition class:

```scala
class AXIAddress(val addrWidthBits: Int, val idBits: Int) extends Bundle {
  val id      = UInt(idBits.W).suggestName("ID")
  //...
}
```

Any idea?

chisel version is 3.2.0

Comment: Actually what I'm tring to do is removing the `_bits` part of the Decoupled IO.

Answer (score 0):

I chisel3 it is not possible to use suggestName inside Bundles. The names emitted into FIRRTL is the chisel variable name. To get the correct naming of the external ports while still being able to use nested bundles internally to represent the AXI interface I have done something like this:

```
class AXIAddress extends Bundle {
  val addr = UInt(32.W)
  val size = UInt(4.W)
  val len = UInt(2.W)

}

class AXIMasterIF extends Bundle {
  val readAddr =  Decoupled(new AXIAddress)
  val writeAddr = Decoupled(new AXIAddress)
}
object AXIMasterIF {
  def apply(): AXIMasterIF = {
    val axi = Wire(new AXIMasterIF)
    axi
  }
}

class AXIExternalIF extends Bundle {
  val AWADDR = Output(UInt(32.W))
  val AWVALID = Output(Bool())
  val AWREADY = Input(Bool())
  val AWSIZE = Output(UInt(4.W))
  val AWLEN = Output(UInt(2.W))

  val ARADDR = Output(UInt(32.W))
  val ARVALID = Output(Bool())
  val ARREADY = Input(Bool())
  val ARSIZE = Output(UInt(4.W))
  val ARLEN = Output(UInt(2.W))

  def connect(int: AXIMasterIF): Unit = {

    this.AWADDR := int.writeAddr.bits.addr
    this.AWVALID := int.writeAddr.valid
    int.writeAddr.ready := this.AWREADY
    this.AWSIZE  := int.writeAddr.bits.size
    this.AWLEN   := int.writeAddr.bits.len
    this.ARADDR  := int.readAddr.bits.addr
    this.ARVALID := int.readAddr.valid
    int.readAddr.ready := this.ARREADY
    this.ARSIZE  := int.readAddr.bits.size
    this.ARLEN   := int.readAddr.bits.len

  }
}

class TopWrapper extends MultiIOModule {
  // First instantive the "internal", nested, representation of the AXI Slave interface
  val axiInt = AXIMasterIF()

  // Then instantiate the external, correctly named, AXI Slave interace that we can connect in Vivado
  val axiExt = IO(new AXIExternalIF).suggestName("MM_AXI_0")

  // Make connections
  axiExt.connect(axiInt)
}
```

The AXIExternalIF is the one that is exposed to the rest of the system. It must be in the top level module of your design. AXIMasterIF which uses AXIAddres is connected to that interface and is used internally to connect things to the AXI interface.

If you wanna play around with it and look at the emitted verilog you can do that at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BAWqXnQVRUyl7aBP76d6Pg)